# How to inplace substitute the content between 2 tags with SED (bash)?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to inplace edit a file with `sed` (Oracle-Linux/Bash).

The content between 2 search-tags (in form of "#"-comments) should get commented out.

Example:

```
Some_Values
#NORMAL_LISTENER_START
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)
         (KEY      = LISTENER)
    )
  )
)
#NORMAL_LISTENER_END
Other_Values
```

Should result in:

```
Some_Values    
#NORMAL_LISTENER_START
# LISTENER =
#   (DESCRIPTION =
#     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)
#          (KEY      = LISTENER)
#     )
#   )
# )
#NORMAL_LISTENER_END
Other_Values
```

The following command already achieves it, but it also puts a comment+blank in front of the search-tags:

```
sed -i "/#NORMAL_LISTENER_START/,/#NORMAL_LISTENER_END/ s/^/# /" ${my_file}
```

Now my research told me to exclude those search-tags like:

```
sed -i '/#NORMAL_LISTENER_START/,/#NORMAL_LISTENER_END/{//!p;} s/^/# /' ${my_file}
```

But it won't work - with the following message as a result:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 56: extra characters after command

I need those SearchTags to be as they are, because I need them afterwards again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, look for specific string and set/unset vars as per that and then print updated(added # in lines) lines as per that, stop updating lines once we find line from which we need not to update lines.

```
awk ' /Other_Values/{found=""} found{$0=$0!~/^#/?"#"$0:$0} /Some_Values/{found=1} 1' Input_file
```

Above will print output on terminal, once you are happy with results you could run following code to do inplace save into Input_file.

```
awk ' /Other_Values/{found=""} found{$0=$0!~/^#/?"#"$0:$0} /Some_Values/{found=1} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
/Other_Values/{ found=""             }   ##If line contains Other_Values then nullify found here.  
found        {  $0=$0!~/^#/?"#"$0:$0 }   ##If found is SET then check if line already has # then leave it as it is OR add # in starting to it.
/Some_Values/{ found=1               }   ##If line contains Some_Values then set found here.
1                                        ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Everything works fine - it's a little bit ugly with creating a temp-file.
Is there a way to do it without it?

Comment: @Dannxy, sure, In GNU Awk 4.1.0 (released 2013) and later, it has the option of inplace editing, then try following: `gawk -i inplace  ' /Other_Values/{found=""} found{$0=$0!~/^#/?"#"$0:$0} /Some_Values/{found=1} 1' Input_file`

Comment: @Dannxy, I have also added detailed explanation in my solution now.

Comment: Seems like we have to use GNU Awk 4.0.2 - so i have to stick to the the tempfile.

But it's fine, you saved my day. Thanks!

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/#NORMAL_LISTENER_START/+1;/#NORMAL_LISTENER_END/-1s/^/#/' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

- Change `Q` to `w` if you're satisfied with the output and *in-place* editing will occur.
- Remove the `,p` If you don't want to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/#NORMAL_LISTENER_START/,/#NORMAL_LISTENER_END/{//!s/^/# /}' file
```

Use a range, delimited by two regexp and insert `#`  before the lines between the regexps but not including the regexps.

Alternative:

```
sed '/#NORMAL_LISTENER_START/,/#NORMAL_LISTENER_END/{s/^[^#]/# &/}' file
```

Or if you prefer:

```
sed '/#NORMAL_LISTENER_START/{:a;n;/#NORMAL_LISTENER_END/!s/^/# /;ta}' file
```